Having problem Deploying on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) with SurrealDB
I'm following the tutorial on
At section 4 of (https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealdb/deployment/google)
When it ask me to
Connect to the cluster and define the initial credentials:
$ export SURREALDB_URL=http://$(kubectl get ingress surrealdb-tikv -o json | jq -r.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip)
$ surreal sql -e $SURREALDB_URL
> DEFINE USER root ON ROOT PASSWORD 'StrongSecretPassword!' ROLES OWNER;

There was a problem with the database: There was a problem with the database: IAM error: Not enough permissions to perform this action
Verify you can connect to the database with the new credentials:
$ surreal sql -u root -p 'StrongSecretPassword!' -e $SURREALDB_URL
> INFO FOR ROOT
[{ namespaces: { }, users: { root: "DEFINE USER root ON ROOT PASSHASH '...' ROLES OWNER" } }]

I feel like I don't have proper permission, and I'm not a Root user. Is there any steps I can take to become Root with sufficient permission so I can define a root password.
